# Why do aggregating a filtered dataset lose the filters of it?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I have this collection:

```
// collection
[
  {_id: 1, name: 'Luigi', childs: [{name: 'one'}, {name: 'two'}], dad_id: 9]},
  {_id: 1, name: 'Mario', childs: [{name: 'four'}, {name: 'five'}], dad_id: 8]},
  {_id: 1, name: 'Alessandro', childs: [{name: 'seven'}, {name: 'six'}], dad_id: 9]},
]
```

and apply this filter to it

```
result = collection.find({ dad_id: 9 })
```

Then I want to aggregate the results and get all the childs singularly, I start with unwinding them
(then I 'll make a projection, etc..) but I already encounter a behavior that I do not understand:
the result contains also the documents with `dad_id` is 8, even if they were already excluded by my query.

```
result.aggregate([
  { "$unwind"=> "$childs" },
]).each do |e| ... end
// => [
  {_id: 1, name: 'Luigi', childs: {name: 'one'}, dad_id: 9]},
  {_id: 1, name: 'Luigi', childs: {name: 'two'}, dad_id: 9]},
  {_id: 1, name: 'Luigi', childs: {name: 'five'}, dad_id: 8]},
  {_id: 1, name: 'Luigi', childs: {name: 'four'}, dad_id: 8]},
  {_id: 1, name: 'Luigi', childs: {name: 'seven'}, dad_id: 9]},
  {_id: 1, name: 'Luigi', childs: {name: 'six'}, dad_id: 9]},
]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Which driver is this? You should not even be able to do that. It's certainly not standard with any other language driver and since it is not working, then this "feature" is not even implemented properly. You're supposed to use a `$match` stage in the aggregation pipeline. And [MongoDB "views"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/) are something completely different.

Comment: Yeah about the view your are right, I am calling them poorly. I will edit the question. The driver any way is ruby. My question remain the same but change the word view with "dataset"

Comment: It's not a matter of what you are calling it, but rather that no officially supported driver has any such feature as you are claiming. So what you need to tell us is "where did you install this driver from?"

Comment: @NeilLunn it is the official gem "mongo" version 2.3.0

Comment: Yeah was just looking at it and it's pretty bad that this is exposed this way. As stated, you are not actually **meant** to even try and use it that way, and no other language driver even allows it. Instead you `$match` in the pipeline itself `collection.aggregate([{ "$match" =>  { dad_id: 9 } },{ "$unwind"=> "$childs" }])`. So the "bugginess" in the driver is the `find()` returns a "Collection View" which exposes an `aggregate()` method which should not actually be there. Do it with the `Collection` method like everyone else does.

Comment: Try using select in this case    
     collection.select { |a| a[:dad_id] == 9 }

Answer (score 0):

You can not chain input from one query to another query like that.

Either use search query ex. Model.find(id) or aggregation framework.

[Aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) provides you the functionality to create a pipeline (ex. match,unwind,lookup,project).

To utilize mongodb indexing always try to use "$match" first in the pipeline

```
match = { "$match" => { "dad_id" =>9} }
unwind = {"$uwind"=>"$childs"}
pipeline = [match,unwind]
collection.aggregate(pipeline).each do |obj|
end
```